# Documents to use to Increse chance of getting UK standard Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I have applied for UK standard visa as per the application. 
I am taking a work related training funded by my organization. What additional document should I give to increase my chances of getting a Visa.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don’t state what documents you already have it’s impossible to comment on what additional documents might be helpful, however this Guide provides a comprehensive list https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf